# Programming SAM uC family without ATmel Studio

Tags: eclipse, arm

I've asked this question on  :https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ 
with no success, So I'm trying my luck here.

I've designed a board that used a SAM uC (Cortex M0+). I don't want to use the ATmel Stduio, I want to learn how to use eclipse and arm-gcc and OpenOCD ( still can't understand, what this one is for ?). So  my question is it possible to do that and if yes, does anyone has hint how can I proceed ?

I've installed the 3 parts,and this is the farthest  I could get: 
[image]

Comment: _"I want to learn how to... ...my question is it possible to do that"_ - I think there's only one person in the world capable of knowing whether that's possible or not. FWIW OpenOCD is a debugger and flashing tool, as a bit of basic searching would reveal.

Comment: @Notlikethat ?  do get what  do you mean with your comment, and how is it suppose to help to solve the problem ?

Comment: What _is_ the problem? You've named some tools you want to use, asked if it's possible for you to learn how to use them, and posted a picture of a dialog box. From that, the obvious hint on how to proceed would seem to be "try clicking the 'Next' button". More generally, Stack Overflow is not a tutorial site, and "I don't know what I'm doing" does not constitute an on-topic question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Notlikethat, what is it that you cant figure out.

1) Yes, I have dozens or hundreds of bare metal microcontroller examples that use the gnu toolchain, no ides, just the command line.  No problems there whatsoever.

2) OpenOCD is an open source tool that knows how to speak to the on chip debuggers, in particular ARM ones.  And it supports JTAG and SWD which is what your cortex-m0+ will have if exposed (which it most likely is).

3) which SAM microcontroller there are hundreds of different ones over a decade or so, the cortex-m0+ certainly narrows that down from what is actually more like thousands to more like hundreds of different ones.  Narrow it down to at least one family.  Is it the popular SAMD21?  I have personally used one of those, and using openocd and gcc is quite doable without any need for an IDE from anyone.  Just add a text editor.

I prefer to use a $10 st discovery or nucleo board as my SWD debugger, remove a couple of the jumpers and you can use that st-link front end for other microcontrollers st or not st.

The chip documentation as well as google will show you how to hook all this up and talk to the chip.

Do you have just a raw chip or do you have it on a board, one you made or one you bought?

Your question is the equivalent of, I have a Ford, and I dont know what size brake pads I need and do I have to have the dealer install them.

Is it a truck is it a car, which one, how many models/variations have they had in the last hundred or so years?  Look up the sizes/parts in a manual.  And the latter is yes of course you can do it yourself, or have someone else install them, you dont have to go to the dealer.

Comment: thanks for replying. I'm using the SAML21 uC on a board I've designed, and I couldn't find any tutorial to how to use openOCd with a SAM0+ familly  :/ . So thanks again